# Admob integration in my app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob

I'm trying to add admob into my android app, but I keep having this error in eclipse:

```
Element type "com.admob.android.ads.AdView" must be followed by either attribute specifications, 
 ">" or "/>".
```

The code is:

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.SampleApp"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <com.admob.android.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  myapp:backgroundColor="#000000" 
  myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF" 
  myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"</com.admob.android.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>

  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00BFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_stupnjevi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_grad"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_grad"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_glavna"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_stupnjevi"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/img01d" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_grad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/img_glavna"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_dan1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:maxLength="3"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_dan1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/img01n" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_stupnjevi1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_dan2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:maxLength="3"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_dan2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/img11d" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_stupnjevi2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_dan3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:maxLength="3"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_dan3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/img13n" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_stupnjevi3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_stupnjevi"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grad"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_tlak"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawablePadding="10dip"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/e2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_vlaznost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawablePadding="10dip"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/d1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_brzina"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawablePadding="10dip"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/wind"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_stanje"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### What I should do to solve this?

i got this error too:
The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

Comment: read the error message, especially the `">"` part and then have a close look after `myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"`

Comment: thanks zapl, but I got this after i fix that : The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

Comment: Oh you have 2 root elements (linear layout then relative layout) get rid of one.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
<com.admob.android.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 myapp:backgroundColor="#000000" 
 myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF" 
 myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"></com.admob.android.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: thank  you user2675569,but i got this rror when i solve that it's :   The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.